# Unable to establish a TLS connection using Rust, Mio and TlsConnector

Tags: ssl, rust, websocket, rust-tokio, mio

I'm trying to create a websocket client using `tokio_tungstenite` and `mio` but I couldn't initialize a stream because of handshake issues. Here is the code I have:

```rust
let addr: Vec<_> = ws_url
    .to_socket_addrs()
    .map_err(|err| ClientError {
        message: err.to_string(),
    })
    .unwrap()
    .collect();

println!("{:?}", addr);

let connector = TlsConnector::new().unwrap();
let stream = TcpStream::connect(addr[0]).unwrap();
let mut stream = match connector.connect(ws_url.as_str(), stream) {
    Ok(stream) => Ok(stream),
    Err(err) => match err {
        native_tls::HandshakeError::Failure(err) => Err(ClientError::new(format!(
            "Handshake failed: {}",
            err.to_string()
        ))),
        native_tls::HandshakeError::WouldBlock(mh) => match mh.handshake() {
            Ok(stream) => Ok(stream),
            Err(err) => Err(ClientError::new(format!( // <-- the handshake process was interrupted
                "Handshake failed: {}",
                err.to_string()
            ))),
        },
    },
}?;
```

This code fails on `mh.handshake()` with an error: `the handshake process was interrupted`.
Does anyone know why that happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research decided to not use mio completely and create an event loop manually. This is doable but too time consuming for a simple task I do.

If you were to create a single threaded event loop, you can just use `tungstenite` and `set_nonblocking` method of the underling socket:

```rust
let url = Url::parse(ws_url.as_str()).unwrap();
match tungstenite::connect(url) {
    Ok((mut sock, _)) => {
        let s = sock.get_mut();

        match s {
            tungstenite::stream::MaybeTlsStream::Plain(s) => s.set_nonblocking(true),
            tungstenite::stream::MaybeTlsStream::NativeTls(s) => {
                s.get_mut().set_nonblocking(true)
            }
            x => panic!("Received unknown stream type: {:?}", x),
        }
        .map_err(|err| ClientError::new(format!("Failed to unblock the socket: {}", err)))
        .unwrap();

        Ok(Box::new(KrakenWsClient { sock }))
    }
    Err(err) => Err(ClientError {
        message: format!(
            "Failed to establish websocket connection: {}",
            err.to_string()
        ),
    }),
}
```

Then reading will look like this:

```rust
fn next_message(&mut self) -> Result<Option<Message>> {
    match self.sock.read_message() {
        Ok(msg) => self.parse_msg(msg),
        Err(err) => match err {
            Error::Io(err) => {
                if err.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock {
                    Ok(None)
                } else {
                    Err(ClientError::new(format!(
                        "Error reading from websocket: {}",
                        err
                    )))
                }
            }
            _ => Err(ClientError::new(format!(
                "Error reading from websocket: {}",
                err
            ))),
        },
    }
}
```

Remember to control timing of yours event loop to prevent it using 100% of CPU. Hope this helps!